# Google Oauh2 Verification Invalid Argument

Tags: google-apps, google-oauth

I'm trying to submit an application for a verification through the Google Console as it has opened from today.

I have verified the domain in question through Goofle Search Console, I have ensured that all the links are set(Policy, Terms of Usage etc), filled the form with information and explanation about the scopes rhat requires verification.

When I submit the form I get no response that it's submited but the response from Network in Developer tools I see it's 400 HTTP Status and I see the following error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I have double checked my steps but still not able to resolve this, any information that you can provide would be great.

Adding Request:

```
https://clientauthconfig.clients6.google.com/v1/brands/ID/submitReview?alt=json&key=AIzaSysnipsnip0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g
```

Above request is PUT, here is the body content

```
{"brandId":"ID","scopeRationale":"","additionalInfo":"","contactEmail":"contactmeialaddress@gmail.com","pendingScopes":["https://mail.google.com/","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"],"category":[1,3,5],"scopeDetails":[{"apiGroup":1,"pendingScopes":["https://mail.google.com/","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"],"scopeRationale":"Why we need access to this scope."},{"apiGroup":2,"pendingScopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"],"scopeRationale":"Additional info why we need this."}]}
```

Comment: update your question with the http request that returned that response

Comment: I have updated the question with request details.

Comment: could you clarify which items are original, and which you have edited. Eg. is the `brandId`, really "ID"?

Comment: I changed the brandid, to ID covered sensitive stuff, also the key I swiched to snipsnip. Nothing else was changed.